# How should I work with empty objects' types?

Tags: typescript

I have a value that's either `{}`, or an object with 30 fields. ESLint suggests that a reasonable type for the former case is `Record<string, never>`, so the compound type looks like `Record<string, never> | MyBigObjectType`.

I'm trying to discriminate between the two cases using the presence or absence of a field `Foo`. Unfortunately, I can't use `"Foo" in val` or `!!val.Foo` because the type checker supposes that it could be present in `Record<string, never>`. But it can't! That's the whole purpose of `never`!

How do I accomplish this without type casts?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Record<never, never>` as the empty object type then you can use `"Foo" in val` to discriminate.

Comment: I don't get it, is that just a synonym for `{}` that you are using to sidestep an ESLint rule?  Either the rule is bad for your use case (i.e., you really *do* want `{}`) or this solution doesn't solve the underlying problem, for example, that `{}` doesn't actually prohibit non-empty objects like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDGORw).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared how you're creating or using these objects, but if using an assertion (cast) is specifically the problem, you can use a function returning a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for compile-time and runtime safety.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&module=1&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.4.4#code/PTAECIEMDtQewEYCsCmBjALqA7gSwwBagDMADKAGa4oA2AJgM7gCwAUBgJ4AOKoAshwBCuAOYB5ZOgwAVbrwC8oAN5tQlOHABcoBhgBOuaCIDcq0Akh7t0AK4BbBCj2nWakKBQY0AOl9sAvi5sFDbQmLhwsLgMAhKomKAAFABukDQ2KNqI8RgAlNqp6bzR-EKicVKyPMpm7mgE6ADWhiI6PGi4VCh0OrgAXrxwFKCNKBwMoDA9XHooDChhg8MA5BQay6AzcDx6nAA0tWAINlgccDagaDCgdnB0nRygGHCU+KBnNnqgswCONrizOwLDAMMyzDCfWAVTDeUbjFJpDK5bw0BYiQigeRYkjkABkuNAq3WoEMoEKGRc-jYwVC4UilFgCKK2gEwnEkkwVRQ+TJcFwPSUVNYbDQkV08AAjJjlIFgtBEnAJbljKB3NBtig2J0ktFYhyMAqlbkGYblaqwHBGtTWHR0DRLLxRdBxXAAExZfUuCjyt1mtUarXDRK6jjQg2+43ehWuv0Wq3Cm12h2XMVYODEFlldk5Llen3EWPwRpAA)

```ts
// "an object with 30 fields"
type MyBigObjectType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  // etc...
};

function isMyObject (value: object): value is MyBigObjectType {
  // checking specified size of keys and presence of 'foo' property,
  // but you can modify to fit your requirements
  return Object.keys(value).length === 30 && 'foo' in value;
}

function fn (value: MyBigObjectType): void {}

const o1 = {};
fn(o1); // nope
if (isMyObject(o1)) fn(o1); // ok

declare const o2: object;
fn(o2); // nope
if (isMyObject(o2)) fn(o2); // ok

declare const o3: MyBigObjectType;
fn(o3); // ok
```